# How to debug a JupyterDash app using VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly, plotly-dash, jupyterdash

*This is going to be a self-answered post, but that only means that I've got an* idea *of a solution, and that I'm very eager to hear about more efficient and stable approaches to the challenge in question.*

---

I would like to know how you can combine the powers of [`JupyterDash`](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash) and [`VSCode`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) in order to run a debugging process for an `.ipynb` file that involves all of the following steps:

1. stepping into code,
2. running code line by line,
3. inspecting variables,
4. setting breakpoints,
5. inspecting callbacks, and
6. interactively editing variables.

I believe I've tried every imaginable combination of:

- Step into code with `F10`
- `Run > Start Debugging (F5)` from the VSCode menu
- `Run and Debug (ctrl+Shift+D)` from the Jupyter Notebook menu
- Inspecting variables through `JUPYTER:VARIABLES` in the VSCode Debug Console

Still I don't feel I've found a work-flow that is 100% satisfactory when it comes to interactivity and stability. And perhaps this isn't the best approach at all? Suggestions that do not include `JupyterDash` are therefore more than welcome.`

---

#### System info:

```
Python 3.9.6
VScode 1.60.2
Plotly 5.1.0
JupyterDash 0.4.0
```

Answer (score 5):

I'll base this suggestion on the code presented [here](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-jupyterdash-811f1f57c02e) to produce a basic dash app with an interactive figure and a dropdown that triggers a callback:

[image]

---

#### Part 1 & 2 - Stepping into code and running code line by line

---

By default for a an `.ipynb` file,  `F10` in VSCode will trigger `Step into function` and place a yellow arrow at the first line of a cell. You can then step through your code line by line by hitting `F10` again.

#### Figure 1.1 - Stepping into code with `F10`

[image]

---

#### Part 3. inspecting variables

---

After stepping through `df = px.data.tips()`, you can find the variable under `JUPYTER:VARIABLES` in the `Debug Console`:

#### Figure 3.1 - Debug console and variables

[image]

You can also inspect the contents of `df` by clicking the icon highlighted above to `Show variable in data viewer`:

#### Figure 3.2 - Data viewer

[image]

---

#### Part 4 - Setting breakpoints

---

If you've got some data manipulation going on within a callback you can set a breakpoint inside the callback:

#### Figure 4.1 -  Set breakpoint.

[image]

#### Part 5 - Inspecting callbacks

In order to make the process move on to that particular breakpoint, you can hit `F5` or even trigger the callback through the Dash App that this code sample produces. For example by choosing `aggsunset` from the dropdown menu:

#### Figure 5.1 - Make a selection to trigger callback debugging

[image]

Now you should notice that nothing happens in the figure itself. And if you go back to VSCode you'll see that the debugging process has moved on to your breakpoint.

#### Figure 5.2 - Code halting a breakpoint after callback is triggered

[image]

As you can see, a new variable is defined withing the callback as  `df2 = df.copy()`. Strange as it is though, now you can only see the local variables of the callback:

#### Figure 5.2 - Jupyter Variables while debugging

[image]

But one neat thing here is that you can inspect the input from the dropdown in your app, which is:

```
colorscale = 'agsunset'
```

What's even cooler is that every time you change your dropdown value and trigger the callback, the value is updated under `JUPYTER:VARIABLES`:

#### Section 6 - Interactively editing variables

#### Figure 6.1 - Changing variables while debugging callbacks

[image]

If you move on to the `DEBUG CONSOLE` tab, you can take a closer a look at `df2` with `df2.tail()`:

#### Figure 6.2 - Inspect new variables

[image]

And you can even add a new column with `df2['new_var] = 1`:

Comment: Hi vestland, I am trying to use your code and follow your debug process, why after hit F5, the debug process is automatically terminated? it never move to the breakpoint? any suggestion to check? I can run your code without any error. but debugging is not working which is what I trying to do exactly. Thanks