# how to debug in dash jupyter notebook?

Tags: plotly-dash

when running dash in jupyter notebook, how to do debugging?

typically, I use below if I just run jupyter notebook,

import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

However with dash, it doesn't work, it just show ipdb> , then no prompt for me to enter for debugging.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using VSCode, you could consider [@vestland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69353859/how-to-debug-a-jupyterdash-app-using-vscode)

Comment: Thanks Derek, no I am not using VSCode, just jupyter notebook. any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Thank you Derek, I will switch to VSCode.